# Find the cardinality of $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < x^3 +y^3< \pi^{21} \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find the cardinality of $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 :  0 < x^3 +y^3< \pi^{21} \}$ 
This is my idea to solve this, but I am not sure whether or not it's correct: 
I want to use the Cantor - Bernstein theorem. 
 
We can say that $S \subseteq R^2 $. But now, on the other hand, we can fix $x = 0 $ and see what values of $y$ meet the restrictions: it turns out that $ 0 < y < \sqrt[3]{\pi^{21}}$ And now, we can say, that 
$\{ 0\} \times (0, \sqrt[3]{\pi^{21}}) \subseteq S.$ We know that the cardinalities of both of these boundries are $\mathfrak c$, thus $|S| = \frak c$

Comment: This is a great answer. Note that $\sqrt[3]{\pi^{21}}=\pi^7$ though.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly well

Comment: You don't need Cantor-Bernstein unless you want to prove there is a bijection.  You are just comparing cardinalities by finding a subset of your set and a superset that have the same cardinality.  This shows your set is the same.  This is all you need.  Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works.

Here's an alternate solution, perhaps more generic . . .

We know that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, hence 
$$|S| \le |\mathbb{R}^2|=|\mathbb{R}|= {\frak{c}}$$
Note that $S$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence $S$ contains an open disk, $D$ say.

There is an obvious bijection from $D$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence
$${\frak{c}} = |\mathbb{R}^2|= |D| \le |S|$$

Therefore $|S| = \frak{c}$.